# Maven, IntelliJ Idea and Android Sources

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, javadoc

I am using combination of Maven and IntelliJ Idea.

Although javadoc and sources are shown using Android Module in Idea, I can not see any of them using Android maven.

Any help, how to show sources also with Maven in Idea? Should I set it in `pom.xml` or somewhere in Idea preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [check the related issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-89743) for the workaround:

> manually attach the sources to "Maven: com.google.android..." project library

See the [Module Dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) for details how to do it.

Comment: Could you be please more specific? I am also struggling with this problem. I was able to override maven settings by manually deleting them and replacing them with those from Android package, but when I refresh IntelliJ settings and project structure with Maven, everything is lost again. Is there any permanent solution?

Comment: There is no permanent solution if you are using Maven and re-importing the project.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you downloaded the sources from the Android SDK for the target that you are using in your project.

Now in IntelliJ, under Project Structure (CMD+;) => Modules => Dependencies you should be seeing "Maven: com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4" and also "Android X.X Platform (java version... )". Select the "Android X.X" and press the up arrow at the bottom to move it up so it's at the top.

Now you should be running with the SDK module which include the sources